# Arduino Magnetometer state change

Tags: c, arduino, magnetometer

I currently have a Arduino connected with magnetometer.  When metal is detected it shows a 1 but when there is no metal it is a 0.  I currently want a count to detect when there is a change in state but ONLY when it goes from a 0 to 1 not a 11 or 10.  I have a last state variable set up to capture the previous state and on the next loop back it compares with the current state.  Then from there it will send a "2" to my raspberry pi which I have connected.  But for some reason the state detect doesn't work.  The last State keeps changing with the current state.  Can anyone help check out my code.

```
    /*      Intialize Variables    */ 
    byte data[32]= {0};                           //Data buffer for testing data transfer speeds
    int k=0;
    float headingdegrees;
    boolean VehicleDetected;
    float high;
    float low;
    float Average;
    float Sum = 0;
    unsigned int Counter = 0; //number of attempted transmissions
    unsigned int fail_counter = 0; //number of failed transmissions
    unsigned int success_counter = 0; //number of successful transmissions
    unsigned long  rxTimer;          //Counter and timer for keeping track transfer info
    unsigned long startTime, stopTime;  
    bool TX=1,RX=0,role=0;
    bool car_detected = 0;
    int inPin_on = 4;   // pushbutton connected to digital pin 4
    int inPin_off = 5; 
    int val = 0;     // variable to store the 
    int fsrPin = 0;     // the FSR and 10K pulldown are connected to a0
    int fsrReading;     // the analog reading from the FSR resistor divider
    int fsrVoltage;     // the analog reading converted to voltage
    unsigned long fsrResistance;  // The voltage converted to resistance, can be very big so make "long"
    unsigned long fsrConductance; 
    long fsrForce;       // Finally, the resistance converted to force
    unsigned int percentage_Transmission = 100;
    const unsigned int reset_counter = 5; //number of transmissions before reset
    unsigned int arr_transmission_percentage[reset_counter] = {0};
    unsigned int arr_index = 0; //To be used for indexing through percentage array
    unsigned int i = 0; 
    unsigned int temp = 0; 
    float TxRxAve = 100; //Average Transmission percentage 
    uint32_t displayTimer = 0;
    int changeDetected = 0;
    int lastState = 0;
        int sendChange = 2;

     if ( headingdegrees > high ){
       VehicleDetected = 1;
       }
     else if(headingdegrees < low){
       VehicleDetected =1;
       }
     else{
       VehicleDetected = 0;
     }

    //Detect the state change

 delay(100);
 if(lastState == 0 && VehicleDetected == 1){
  changeDetected = 1;
 }
 else{
  changeDetected = 0;
 }


//store the current state
// lastState = VehicleDetected;

/***** Sending Data****/
  mesh.update();
  // Send to the master node every 5 second

  if (millis() - displayTimer >= 5000) {
    displayTimer = millis();

   //if changeDetected = 1 then send a 2 to the raspberry pi
    // Send an 'M' type message containing the current millis()
    if (changeDetected == 1){
      if (!mesh.write(&sendChange, 'M', sizeof(sendChange))) {

        // If a write fails, check connectivity to the mesh network
        if ( ! mesh.checkConnection() ) {
          //refresh the network address
          Serial.println("Renewing Address");
          mesh.renewAddress();
        } else {
          Serial.println("Send fail, Test OK");
        }
      } else {
            Serial.print("Begin \n");
            Serial.print("Average:"); Serial.println(Average);   
            Serial.print("Heading (degrees): "); Serial.println(headingdegrees);
            Serial.print("Sending Count: "); Serial.println(sendChange);
            Serial.print("Last State: "); Serial.println(lastState);
            Serial.print("Change: "); Serial.println(changeDetected);   
            //Serial.print("Data: "); 
            //Serial.println(data[0]);
            Serial.print("Send OK: "); Serial.println(displayTimer);
            Serial.print("End \n\n\n");
        ;
      }
    }
    //if changeDetected = 0 then simplay send the vehicledDetected
    else{
    if (!mesh.write(&VehicleDetected, 'M', sizeof(VehicleDetected))) {

      // If a write fails, check connectivity to the mesh network
      if ( ! mesh.checkConnection() ) {
        //refresh the network address
        Serial.println("Renewing Address");
        mesh.renewAddress();
      } else {
        Serial.println("Send fail, Test OK");
      }
    } else {
          Serial.print("Begin \n");
          Serial.print("Average:"); Serial.println(Average);   
          Serial.print("Heading (degrees): "); Serial.println(headingdegrees);
          Serial.print("Vehicle Detected:"); Serial.println(VehicleDetected);
          Serial.print("Last State: "); Serial.println(lastState);
          Serial.print("Change: "); Serial.println(changeDetected); 
          //Serial.print("Data: "); 
          //Serial.println(data[0]);
          Serial.print("Send OK: "); Serial.println(displayTimer);
          Serial.print("End \n\n\n");
      ;
     }
    }
  }
 while (network.available()) {
    RF24NetworkHeader header;
    payload_t payload;
    network.read(header, &payload, sizeof(payload));
    Serial.print("Received packet #");
    Serial.print(payload.counter);
    Serial.print(" at ");
    Serial.println(payload.ms);
    delay(500);
  }
   lastState = VehicleDetected;
}
```

Comment: There is too much missing code, and too much code which is irrelevant to your problem. For example, where are the variable definitions (VehicleDetected, changeDetected)? Does the mesh code have anything to do with the problem ? Try to make a smaller program that shows your problem. It is possible that in doing so you will find the error yourself. If not, maybe we will. But with the info you sent, this is very difficult to do.

Comment: Okay I took out some code that is not part of the problem.  The first section is variable definitions, then second is it detecting the change, and the last part is sending the data to my raspberry pi.

Comment: Also, often with this kind of measurement the transition between the two states can be quite noisy, with the status bouncing back and forth several times. Look into debouncing if your input is digital or hysteresis if it is analogic and you are watching a threshold.

Comment: You were right, the states were bouncing back and forth way too fast for the state change to catch it and send because it only sends every 5 seconds.  I slowed down the time it takes for it to capture the measurement and it seemed to work.  Thank you